# problema a la hora de relacionar tablas en MySql

Tags: php, laravel-5

Dentro de mi DB de mysql tengo una tabla llamada profesores, la cual luce algo así.

```
Nombre | email | id | password ...
```

el problema es que tengo que relacionarla con otra llamada **`grupos`**, (es para organizar de forma clásica a un grupo con sus múltiples profesores)

la tabla **`profesores`** luce algo así:

```
Nombre | image | id | fecha ...
```

normalmente esto se solucionaría poniendo en alguno de las dos tablas un campo llamado **`grupo_id`** o **`profesores_id`**, el problema es que de hacer alguna de esas dos cosas me quedaría limitado a una sola en cualquiera de esas, es decir o me quedaría que un grupo posee un solo profesor, o que un profesor posee un solo grupo, lo cual obviamente no pasa en la realidad y no quiero que sea así.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crea una tabla intermedia `profesores_grupos` con dos campos: `profesorId`y `grupoId`.
Luego crea relaciones entre las tablas que tienes y los dos campos de ésta tabla.

Con eso tendrás relaciones varios a varios como tú quieres.